# Unity WebGL/Parse Sign Up via REST API returns Unauthorized

Tags: parse-platform, unity-webgl

I am working on integrating Parse with Unity for WebGL. Since the Parse plugin currently doesn't work with WebGL, I am forced to use the REST API (or edit the source code, which hasn't been working). Unfortunately, Parse doesn't have any documentation on how to use the REST API within the Unity/WebGL app, so I'm not even sure if I'm doing it right. Regardless, attempting to sign up with the code I posted below only gives me a "401 Unauthorized" error, at least in the Unity editor (I currently can't test to see if an actual build on my server will do anything different). I've also tried using the Client Key instead of the REST-API Key, but that had the same effect. Could someone give me pointers on where to go from here?

Here's my code:

```
string url = "https://api.parse.com/1/users";
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("X-Parse-Application-Id", APP_ID);
form.AddField("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", REST_ID);
form.AddField("X-Parse-Revocable-Session", 1);
form.AddField("Content-Type", "application/json");
string newDataString = "{\"username\":\"" + email + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\",\"email\":\"" + email + "\"}";
WWW www = new WWW(url, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newDataString), form.headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error seems to point to a direction: the headers are not properly formatted. As an example, I was getting the same error because in the text field of an Authorization header there was a blank space between the = and " characters, like this:

```
token= "ajifidjoa...
```

So, first off, I suggest you to use something like Postman or any other REST client plugins for Chrome and test your call using them.
This way you should be able to understand better where the error is hidden.

Moreover, working with REST calls in Unity I found that a WebClient is way better for doing POST; sample code:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", json_string_to_post);
        }
```